# why only first letter of column coming from mysql database in php?

Tags: mysql

my database is

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
       `id` int(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `name` varchar(50),
       `description` varchar(255),
       `visible` varchar(10),
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET utf8;
```

and php code is

```
     $display = query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id ASC");
     foreach($display as $row) {
      echo $row['id'];
      echo $row['name'];
      echo $row['description'];     
}
```

what is wrong in my code ? data is not displayed and when it display only first letter of field is displayed. All the configuration and connection settings are fine. Pls help

Comment: what is in this function query ? do you mean mysql_query

Answer (score 1):

```
var_dump($row);
```

Comment: it displays int(4)

string(4) "sdfs"

string(12) "fsgdfgfdgfds"

string(3) "dgd"

Comment: How do I retrieve array values ? please help.

Comment: well, you have no array then - you have only scalar value in `$row`

Comment: @sagarmatha you need to show your `query()` function. We cannot know what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's the same pitfall I fell into once :)
Don't you have only one row in your table?
If this query() function is kinda too smart one, determining return type by returned data, it can be a reason.
Make it return nested array, not one row. 
And define result type explicitly, not automatically based on returned data. Add a parameter to indicate what kind of result you want.

However, such a function is very good approach. Only a few people have an idea of devising such a function instead of constant hassle with numerous API functions.

but if you *expect* just one row, then

```
$row = query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id ASC");
echo $row['id'];
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['description'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the this same problem using CodeIgniter.

The problem for me was that I was trying to echo out the array value using an associative key when it was just a numerically indexed array. I'm surprised it worked at all.

So my array was built like so:

```
$result = $this->ci->db->get('role');

if($result->num_rows() > 0)
{
    foreach($result->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $roles[$row['id']] = $row['name'];  
    }   
}
```

When I tried to use the array like so:

```
foreach($roles as $role)
{
    echo $role['name'];
}
```

It would only print out the first letter of each value.

When I changed the array to be built like this:

```
        $roles[$row['id']] = array('name' => $row['name']);
```

Everything worked as expected.

Hope this helps someone.